# Getting object property in RecyclerView when item is clicked

Tags: android, object, android-recyclerview

I'm using **RecyclerView** to bind a list of object in an adapter.

With **SetOnItemClickListener** I'm able to intercept clicks on elements of the RecycleView, but I need to access to the properties of the binded object (e.g: the field name) to send to other activity when is clicked on the button.

How would this be possible ?

Comment: recyclerview does not have an `onItemClickListener` you need to implement your own callback system

Comment: I've implemented it, is not this the issue... I need to get object property when item is clicked

Comment: post your code if you already implemented stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing the idea of ListView and RecylerView. RecylerView is ViewHolder oriented, so you should handle click event on ViewHolder itself. It's very simple.

```
public class ObjectClass {
    public String property1;
    public String property2;
    ...
}

public class ObjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ObjectViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ObjectClass> mObjects;

    public ObjectAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public ObjectClass getItem(int position) {
        return mObjects != null ? mObjects.get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mObjects != null ? mObjects.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ObjectViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ObjectViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // bind the item with ViewHolder here
        holder.item = getItem(position);
    }

    public static class ObjectViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            View.OnClickListener {
        private ObjectClass item;

        public ObjectViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // do stuff with item's properties...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I was looking for. I've missed the getItem(int position)  method in my adapter :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.gmehdibalti.jasonpracticwthree;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by G Mehdi Balti on 5/16/2016.
 */
public class myAdapter  extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.ContactViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<UserModel> list;
    Activity activity;

    public myAdapter(ArrayList<UserModel> list, Activity activity) {
        this.list = list;
        this.activity = activity;
    }





    @Override
    public myAdapter.ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell, parent, false);
        ContactViewHolder cvh=new ContactViewHolder(v);
        return cvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myAdapter.ContactViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ContactViewHolder cvh=holder;
        UserModel abc=list.get(position);
        cvh.txt_id.setText(abc.getId());
        cvh.txt_name.setText(abc.getName());
        cvh.txt_email.setText(abc.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_name;
        TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_email;
        public ContactViewHolder(View itemView) {


            super(itemView);


            txt_id = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Id_item);
            txt_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name_item);
            txt_email = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_email_item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to explain why the OP's code doesn't work and explain how your code works. Then the OP learns more.